# What should be the return type of range: range or NSRange?

Tags: ios, swift, string, range, swift4

I am using swift 4 and this code snippet throws me an error while initialising *n1* variable:

```
 func caseInsensitiveSearch(searchString: String) -> NSRange?  {
        if let range = self.range(of: searchString, options: .caseInsensitive),
            let n1 = NSRange(range, in: self) {
                return n1
        }
        return nil
    }
```

Can I pass pass directly the **Range**? or it is necessary to convert it in to **NSRange**.

Any idea??

Comment: "if let range = self.range(of: searchString, options: .caseInsensitive)"  You don't have any optionals to unwrap,if let is used exclusively to unwrap optionals.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are trying to unbind a non optional value, you can directly return it like so:

```
func caseInsensitiveSearch(searchString: String) -> NSRange?  {
        if let range = self.range(of: searchString, options: .caseInsensitive) {
                return  NSRange(range, in: self)
        }
        return nil
    }
```